# What reinforcement learning algorithm should I use in continuous states?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, algorithm, dqn, ddpg

I want to use reinforcement learning in an environment I made. The exact environment doesn't really matter, but it comes down to this: The amount of different states in the environment is infinite e.g. amount of ways you can put 4 cars at an intersection, but the amount of different actions is only 3 e.g. go forward, right or left. The state exists out of five numbers. My question is: what algorithm should I use or at least what kind of algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [Deep Q-Learning](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14236).

Comment: Is DQN really good when there are infinite different states the environment can be

Comment: @SirPVP Yes, it is a function approximator method which is precisely for infinite state spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much.